# JQuery Promise .notify needs Closure...

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, jquery-deferred

I think I am having a problem with closure/scoping.  When I observer the progress of `MyObject` i always get the value final value of `i`.

**Example**

```
var a = new MyObject();
a.progress(function(msg){console.log(msg)}); // always prints 1000/1000
```

**Observable Object**

```
    function MyObject()
    {
       var this.dfd = $.Deferred();
      return this.dfd.promise();
    } 

    MyObject.prototype.aProcess = function()
        {
            var self = this;
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                (function(i)
                {

                   self.notify("Updating " + (i+1) + "/" + 1000); 
                   // Bunch of Processes

                })(i);
            }
        }

    MyObject.prototype.notify = function(message)
    {
        console.log(message) // works fine
        this.dfd.notify(message);   
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashanova/Xe47R/)

Comment: It prints correct numbers in the jsfiddle... Also, since you don't return instance of `MyObject`, what is the point of the class?

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken, this logs `1/1000` all the way to `1000/1000`, just as it is supposed to. Although it does print `1000/1000` twice...

Comment: `console.log` *may* print the *actual* value on the moment of viewing not on the moment of execution of the code. So if you see that and don't believe your eyes - try to use js debugger instead. PS: as @Esailija noted below: it's only valid for js objects, not for primitive types

Comment: @zerkms that's not the case for primitive values

Comment: @Esailija: yep, I'm in the process of giving a note about that ;-)

Comment: @lonesomeday if you remove the log in notify, I am interested in the progress log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `.process` before returning the deferred, so by the time you attach progress listener, the notifications have already run.

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xe47R/2/

```
function MyObject() {
    this.dfd = $.Deferred();
    //Don't explicitly return an object, otherwise the class is useless.
};
MyObject.prototype.process = function() {
    //The closure was useless here
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        this.notify("Updating " + (i + 1) + "/" + 1000);
    }
};
MyObject.prototype.notify = function(message) {
    //Remove console.log from here to avoid confusion
    this.dfd.notify(message);
}
var a = new MyObject();
a.dfd.promise().progress(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
}); // always prints 1000/1000
a.process();​
```

Comment: that works.  In implementation the class is a parser. I wanted to just pass the constructor in some JSON which it then parses to a webSql db and be able to observe it progress/done/fail.  So Is my approach wrong and its pointless to have the constructor return a promise?

Comment: @CrimsonChin err yes because when you explicitly return an object in a constructor, that object is returned instead of the object created when you call `new`. So you will not have access to the object created, so there is no point of having a class.

Comment: What if I had MyObject.parse return the promise giving a nice clean observer into the class?

Comment: Sure, it's just the constructor function has to return nothing so that the created object is returned when called with `new`

Comment: I can see how you solved this problem and I understand why it occurs.  How can I make MyObject a deferred object? I don't want to have to access MyObjects deferred object (dfd property) I think ultimately what I want is for MyObject to be a deferred object.  is that possible?

Comment: @CrimsonChin Then you simple create a deferred. `var a = $.Deferred()`. You could have a method in MyObject to return the promise though. `var a = new MyObject(), b = a.getPromise()`